# Twitter ouath callback in Spotify Apps

Tags: spotify

How can I set a twitter callback, it doesn't support sp://

my code is

```
auth.showAuthenticationDialog('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' + result.oauth_token, 'sp://geoholium',{ 
                            onSuccess: function(response) {
                                authenticated = true;
                                access_token = response.split('=')[1];
                            },
                            onFailure: function(error) {
                            },
                            onComplete: function() { }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`auth.showAuthenticationDialog` works by watching for requests to the URL given in the second parameter, then intercepting them and passing it to you in the callback instead.

With that in mind, you can set the callback URL to whatever is needed for Twitter's API — for example, `http://mywebsite.com/twitterIsDone` — the request to `http://mywebsite.com/twitterIsDone` will be intercepted for you and will never actually take place.